# htaccess rewrite problem

Tags: htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

Maybe is best way to show my problem in one example.

In my .htaccess :

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/  index.php?act=catalog&category=$1&color=$2&size=$3 [NC,L]
```

With the address `www.site.com/catalog/category-1/red-3/size-3/`  this works excellent

But if you leave out the size, like  `www.site.com/catalog/category-1/red-3/`,  I will be redirected to `www.site.com`.

I want to show all articles with category ID 1 and color which is ID 3.

Comment: for syntax errors : http://www.lyxx.com/freestuff/002.html

Comment: So you're saying you want the last directory, e.g. size-3, to be optional?

Comment: Yes .. can i set some directory to be optional ??

Answer (score 2):

You can have optional parts, if your PHP script accepts an empty `size` parameter and then does what you want.

Try this:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/([a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/)?  index.php?act=catalog&category=$1&color=$2&size=$4 [NC,L]
```

The important changes are one more parenthesized group, followed by an `?` (to make it optional), and an adaption of the capture number from $3 to $4 (since the capturing group for the size is now the 4th one).  (Instead of the number change we could also have used `(?:` instead of the added `(`, I guess.)

Answer (score 1):

You will need to write another `rewrite` rule to match the option of not having a size specified:

```
RewriteRule ^catalog/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/[a-z0-9_-]+-([0-9]+)/ index.php?act=catalog&category=$1&color=$2 [NC, L]
```

Put that as your `second` rewrite since it is the least specific.

Comment: I would like to define a directory as an optional if possible

Comment: You are going to need two rewrite rules, one that matches one regexp and one that matches the other. I'll update my answer with more info

Comment: You can't necessarily set one as `optional`, you just have to make more lines to match all possible options (: